# Translate3d choppy towards the end of the transformation on mobile device

Tags: css, css-transitions, translate3d

I was initially using jQuery's slide functions to slide a page out of view (to reveal another page beneath it) in a Cordova app I'm making, and whilst this worked perfect on my desktop browser, it (now understandably) was quite choppy on the actual mobile device. So I found out the reason for this and learnt that I should use CSS3 animations/transitions for mobile devices, and more specifically Translate3d for anything that may require GPU rendering. So I've made those changes like this:

```
#mainpage{
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s linear;
    transition: all .5s linear;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #111111;
}
#mainpage.out{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
}
```

and I just toggle the 'out' class as necessary.

The transition runs smoothly until about 50px are left on the screen (or the page has about 50px left to reappear), then it stops for about a second before finishing up. I was wondering if anyone has any suggestion as to why this may be the case or if there's maybe an even more efficient way of doing this.

The device I am using has a nVIDIA Tegra 3 CPU with 12-Core High Performance Graphics.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the way you should do the animation.

Try the following:

```
#mainpage {
   z-index: 10;
   top: 0;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #111111;
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear;
   transition: transform .5s linear;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
   transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

#mainpage.out {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
   transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
}
```

First change is, specify the type of the property you want to animate (the `transition` parameter), not sure what you are animating when you write `all`.

Second thing, specify the "back" transition with `translate3d(0,0,0)`. Also not sure, if it makes a difference here, though. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Unfortunately it makes no difference. One thing though, the `transform` in the `-webkit-transition` needs to be `-webkit-transform` - it didn't work without the prefix.

Comment: Of course, you are right, I edited my code accordingly.